# If statement converting 'simple int' to 'series int'

Tags: pine-script

In a trading view pine script I am trying to call `ta.rma` with a dynamic length but everything I try gives me this error in the console:

> Cannot call 'ta.rma' with argument 'length'='length'. An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'simple int' is expected

Using a simple assignment works (ie no error from the ta.rma function):

```
// This works
length = 20
```

But if I use an 'if' statement, length is converted to 'series int' and I have no idea why or how to fix it:

```
length = if syminfo.ticker == 'SPY'
    10
else
    20
```

rma call:

```
ta.rma(high - low, length)
```

I'm using a `//@version=5` script

Comment: Changed the if condition to more accurately reflect what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message tells you, the `length` argument expects a `simple int`.

`simple` is a data type such that their values are known on the first bar and they never change during the execution. You can read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#) to learn more about type systems.

In your case, you are using a conditional operator to assign a value to `length`. This makes it not a `simple` because its value could change depending on your condition. Hence the error message.

```
len1 = input.int(14)
len2 = 14
len3 = math.round(bar_index / 2)

rma = ta.rma(close, 14)    // Fine
rma1 = ta.rma(close, len1) // Fine
rma2 = ta.rma(close, len2) // Fine
rma3 = ta.rma(close, len3) // Error as len3 will be different on each bar
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My condition is based on the selected instrument so are you saying that in this situation it is not possible to keep the value as a simple int? 

The link you shared has this for simple: `Values of “simple” form are known only when a script begins execution on the first bar of a chart’s history, and they never change during the execution of the script.` I do not want the length value to change once its set for a given instrument. I only want it to change if the instrument changes. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: Use a user input for the length?

Comment: Yes I know this is not a great way of doing the indicator but its for my own personal use and I want it to change the length based on the selected symbol. Is that possible while still keeping the value a simple int?

Comment: No, unfortunately, it is not possible.